# When I compile my code with nasm -f elf64 -o I get the error "parser:instruction expected"

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, nasm, x87

I'm trying to calculate a * x^2+b * x+c, with a,b,c,x known. I'm building this code in Linux. When I assemble my NASM code with  `nasm -f elf64 -o` I get the error "parser:instruction expected" on the line with `fstb qword[ebx]` marked below.

My code:

```
%define a qword [ebp+8]
%define b qword [ebp+16]
%define c qword [ebp+24]
%define x qword [ebp+32]

segment .data
pash: dd 0.0001
segment .bss
segment .text

        global  function
function:
        push ebp
        mov ebp,esp
        sub esp,16 
        push ebx

        fld x                   ;st: x
        fld x                   ;st: x,x  
        fmulp st1               ;st: x*x
        fld a                   ;st:a,x*x
        fmulp st1               ;st: a*x*x
        fld b                   ;st:b, a*x*x
        fld x                   ;st:x,b,a*x*x
        fmulp st1               ;st:b*x,a*x*x
        faddp st1               ;st:b*x+a*x*x
        fld c                   ;st:c,b*x,a*x*x
        faddp st1               ;st:c+b*x,a*x*x
        faddp st1               ;st:c+b*x+a*x*x
        fstb    qword[ebx]      ;store result  <-- This line has the error.
        mov eax,1
        jmp quit
quit:
        pop ebx
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: What line is the error indicated on?

Comment: line 30, that means instruction : fstb qword[ebx]

Comment: The mnemonic is incorrect.  Try `fstp`.

Comment: Now i have "instruction not supported in 64 bit-mode"

Comment: Your code is 32 bit code.  Either rewrite your program for 64 bit mode or assembly it for 32 bit mode.  Did you write this code yourself?

Comment: @DianaBîrla: When asked for additional information, edit the information into the question.

Comment: What is “assembly NANS”?

Comment: This is 32-bit code (you can tell because it pushes and pops 32-bit registers), so you should assemble it with `nasm -felf32`.  In 64-bit mode there's no reason to use x87, you can always assume SSE2 for `mulsd` and so on, and the calling convention passes FP args in XMM regs.  Also, this code is pointlessly inefficient, using extra `fld` instead of memory source operands, and e.g. the first 2 instructions could be `fld x` / `fmul st0`.  Loading the same number twice makes no sense.

Comment: i ve understood my mistake, it works with "nans -f elf32 -o" . I began with an complex example and that s wrong.....